# MySQL LONGTEXT doesn't accept an apostrophe '

Tags: mysql

I was building a portal for my college with posting messages option. Hence I used LONGTEXT to store the message in mysql. But somehow the LONGTEXT doesn't accept the apostrophe mark.
It gives following error whenever I post some sentence with apostrophe mark:

```
"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's open singles
 tournament, will Electrical be able to maintain their dominance o' at line 1"
```

PS: not in the escape string, but in `<textarea>`, if I input the apostrophe mark it gives the error!

Comment: Did you try printing the entire SQL query? If not, go ahead and try that, look at the query, then post it on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it with a backslash like

```
SELECT 'This is a escape \' quote test';
```

**EDIT**

If you are taking information directly from a web form and inserting it into a data base - this is a massive security risk. This is how SQL injection is done.

Comment: not that..! i noe that already.. but its in the <textarea> where user puts in their message..!

Comment: Then you need to either process the string yourself or use something like mysql_real_escape_string in php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Sure - the rule is never trust any data that is external - even if you use data from you DB to fill a field on a webform - when it comes back do not trust it and make sure you use things like mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Oh Bobby Tables - how I love you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

1. You copied the value of the long text into your 'query' (presumably an INSERT or UPDATE statement, though it could simply be the value to compare with in a SELECT).
2. You did not notice that the first unescaped single quote after the opening quote terminates the string.

Given that you are using MySQL, I believe you have two options on escaping:

1. Standard SQL (applies to most, if not all, SQL DBMS): use two consecutive single quotes to insert one:

   ```
    ''''                           -- Insert a string consisting of one single quote
    'He said, "Don''t do that!"'   -- A string containing a single quote
   ```
2. MySQL (may also be an option elsewhere, but not every SQL DBMS will recognize it): use a backslash to escape the single quote:

   ```
    '\''                           -- As above
    'He said, "Don\'t do that!"'   -- Also as above
   ```

There may also be functions you can use to do the escaping for you - depending on the host language you are using.  However, the preferred way to get values into an SQL statement, especially ones that might contain random characters, is to use placeholders.  The mechanics depend on the host language in which you are embedding the SQL, but the general idea is:

1. The raw SQL string looks like: `INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(?, ?, ?);`
2. You PREPARE the statement, more or less explicitly.
3. When you execute it, you provide the data as parameters to the EXECUTE.
4. Or, if it is a SELECT statement, you PREPARE it, you DECLARE a cursor for it, then you OPEN the cursor and provide the parameter values at that time.

In one SQL-based language (IBM Informix 4GL):

```
 DEFINE a INTEGER, b DECIMAL(10,2), c VARCHAR(250)

 LET a = 1
 LET b = 99999999.99
 LET c = 'He said, "Don''t do that!"'

 PREPARE p1 FROM "INSERT INTO SomeTable(a,b,c) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
 EXECUTE p1 USING a, b, c

 PREPARE p2 FROM "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE c = ?"
 DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR p2
 OPEN c2 USING c
```

Note that if you do not use placeholders, you have to be extremely careful not to fall into the [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) trap.

Answer (score 0):

use the backslash character to escape the string:

`"Carlito\'s Ways"`

You may need to unescape later, but PHP has a built-in function for that.

```
insert into customers(firstname, lastname) 
values ('Bill', 'O\'Connor');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to escape your apostrophes with a backslash character (`\`), but it would also be intuitive to provide the SQL query that you attempted to execute in order for people to help you further.